# changing value of hidden input tags using Browser from mechanize in python

Tags: python, forms, mechanize, hidden-field, mechanize-python

I am working on a web-scraping project. I am using Browser from mechanize in python.
There is a form with a few hidden input elements. I want to change the value in these hidden elements and then submit the form. How do i do it?

```
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

See their note on hidden form fields http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/faq.html